# SQL: filtering "people" table based on multiple behavior conditions

Tags: sql

Suppose that there are two tables, "people" and "events". (events as in stuff that happened, not as in holiday or organized gatherings)

Suppose people table has 30 columns and 1m rows, whereas events table has 10 columns and 1b rows, stored in MySQL. Suppose events table has an indexed "name" column with cardinality ~100

A sample filter would be

```
Give me all the people,
that did A within last two weeks,
and did not do B within last two weeks,
and did either C or D within past 2 days
```

Suppose we only allow two layers of boolean logic, top level is AND 2nd level is OR (let me know if it's better to flip it), and that both the event (ABCD) and time range are arbitrary inputs from the customer

Suppose this is a frequently used feature where we experiment with filtering combinations

How should I go about implementing this in SQL? Or is a relational database the wrong choice here?

Comment: It’s not at all clear what you are actually asking in your question. If you’re asking for SQL that delivers your sample filter then please update your question with the relevant table definitions and show what SQL you have managed to write yourself

Comment: @NickW More like the general design itself. The two standard people/event tables I mentioned would result in one subquery per condition. I did not restrict the schema in case someone suggests other schemas

Comment: I'm still not clear what response you are expecting to "How should I go about implementing this in SQL?" apart from "write the SQL that gives the result that you want"

Comment: @NickW I'm happy to rephrase that to "implementing this in db schema design / system selection / query" or something else if that would help